# Trouble centering a bitmap on an ImageView

Tags: android, layout, imageview, center, bmp

I have an ImageView (image_view) in an xml and I have the layout gravity set to center and the scale set to center_inside....but when I pass my compressed bmp to the image_view, it puts it on the middle-left of the screen (in portrait mode)...any ideas on a workaround?

here is me setting it to the image view:

```
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap565);
```

I also compress it in an output stream:

```
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filepath);

            bitmap565.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos);

            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Thanks all!

```
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/ImageButton01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/results" android:layout_gravity="top|center"></ImageButton><ImageView
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_weight="1.0" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

    <Button
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textStyle="bold" android:id="@+id/detect_face" android:text="Detect"/>
```

Comment: paste the XML layout, please.

Comment: edited - sorry for poor formatting

Comment: could you post the complete layout? Or at least, all of its parents? ImageViews don't have a gravity, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can solve your problem just using FrameLayout.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ImageView`'s `layout_width` is set to `fill_parent`, so `layout_gravity` won't affect its horizontal position within its parent. Try using `gravity` instead of `layout_gravity`, or `wrap_content` instead of `fill_parent`.

Comment: Hey - I tried but it is still displaying it to the left of center.  I force the app to be in portrait rather than landscape - do you think that's an issue?

Comment: What is the container of these Views? It should also be layout_width="fill_parent".